# Do you have enough Gem-Slots to support 3 offensive Spells?

Tags: path-of-exile

Is it possible to support 3 Damage Spells with each its own support gems with lategame gear?
Would you have to sacrifice support-spells to achieve this?

Not the topic, background:

My goal at the moment is Freezing Pulse + Ice Spear. One for the Shotgun melee range/damage, the other for the sniping range and extra damage versus ranged mobs or bosses. However if there weren't enough slots, I would have to decide for one which is not the topic. Btw the third (or second if the answer is no) is Ball Lightning to trigger  Elemental Equilibrium.

~ This is part of an answer of my initial question ~ Added after getting more knowledge ~

My damage spells:

1. Ice Spear - 5 up to 6 sockets
2. Ball Lightning - 4 sockets
3. Freeze Pulse - 4 sockets

Besides of Damage Spells I need:

1. Reduced mana - 3 up to 4 sockets
2. Chance when Damage (level 20) Taken - 3 up to 4 sockets
3. Chance when Damage (level 1) Taken - 2 up to 4 sockets
4. Lightning Warp -  1 up to 3 sockets
5. Curse -  1 socket (up to 3 if space)
6. Teleport - 1
   (7. Cast when Stunned - 2 sockets) (if space)

Minimum: 11 sockets (no damage spells)
Maximum: 21 sockets (no damage spells)

So the ultimate question is. How many Damage spells can I still equip into sockets (with sufficient support of course) with all this, and what do I have to sacrifice?

Comment: What do you mean by "3 offensive spells"?

Comment: i have described it at the background: Freezing Pulse + Ice Spear + Ball Lightning to trigger Elemental Equilibrium

Comment: Yes, however, it doesn't make sense since you can have 8 spells with the 3 mouse buttons and qwert.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the only thing you're limited by are the amount of gem slots on your equipment.

Comment: I don't think we can answer that without clarification, at least in a satisfactory manner. Technically, yes, your equipment will generally have over six gem slots. But that is as specific an answer as we can give unless you explain what you're worried about sacrificing, what level you're trying to gear up for, and whether there are any additional limitations.

Comment: At the moment I can't explain that because I don't know enough about the game. But I will look if I can find it out to increase my question (but no time today). @slow_excellence I don't get what you mean by "doesn't make sense", 3 fits into 8 spells i can have. My question was about gems, not number of spells. - ok Rereading it, I get why it can be understood otherwise. I fix that.

Comment: @Pvt. Grichmann I have become acquainted with what I need, so I have edited my question, see ~ and following.

Answer (score 3):

Short overview of how many sockets you can have:

1. Weapons

   - 2h weapon = 6 sockets
   - 1h weapon + shield / 2x 1h weapon = 3 sockets + 3 sockets
2. body armour = 6 sockets
3. boots / helmet / gloves = 4 sockets each
4. 2x unset ring = 1 socket each

So now to your setup:

- IceSpear + 5 supports = 6 sockets (chest)
- Ball Lightning + 3 supports = 4 sockets (for example boots)
- Freeze Pulse + 3 supports = 4 sockets (for example helmet)
- Reduced Mana + Auras = 4 sockets (for example gloves)

Now, depending on the setup, you have either 6 sockets in weapon (theoretically can be linked 3 + 3 or 4 + 2, which is very luck dependent, so we consider 2x 3 sockets 1h + shield or dual wield which gives us 3 + 3 sockets):

- cwdt (l20) = 3 sockets (weapon)
- cwdt (l1) + curse = 2 sockets + 1 socket (off hand)
- lightning warp = 1 socket (ring 1)
- teleport = 1 socket (ring 2)

So all in all it's possible with endgame gear, but you have to give up some implicit ring mods for sockets.

Answer (score 2):

First I would like to apologize for the confusion.  I was looking at your question with an experienced player viewpoint and not a beginner one. To answer your question, you are only limited by what gems you want to do, how many slots you have, and which support gems you attach. 
If you find a piece of equipment you really like and will stick with for a while, I suggest modifying it to suit your needs. This can be done by using the in-game [currency items](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Currency#section_1).

- The `Jeweller's Orb` will randomly reforge how many sockets you have on the item.
- The `Chromatic Orb` will randomly recolor **ALL** of the sockets.
- The `Orb of Fusing` will randomly link sockets on an item.

These three orbs will allow you to customize your equipment to suit your needs, but make sure you have plenty of them farmed up beforehand. It can take quite a while with a TON of resources to get an item forged with the slots you prefer!

Comment: How many slots can I have per item?

Comment: Up to four for 1-handed weapons/shields, helmets, gloves, and boots. And up to 6 for chest pieces and 2-handed weapons.

Comment: Just to clarify, 1-handed weapons and shields can only have 3 slots max each.